# Need help with getting the current memory on a program

Tags: c++, windows

I need to get the up to date memory useage of a program that is running. i googled it and found [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx) this looks like what i needed but i can't get it to work.
It wont take the handle i find for the window and i am not really sure what they want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <Psapi.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

HANDLE hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,TEXT("Calculator"));


PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS ppsmemCounters;

DWORD cb;

BOOL WINAPI GetProcessMemoryInfo(hwnd, ppsmemCounters, cb);

return 0;
}
```

I am just trying to find the window's calculator for now.
One of the errors i get is Error:a value of type "HANDLE" cannot be used to initialize an entity type "BOOL".
Another is "error C2078: too many initializers".
I am using VC++ 2010, and my os is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetProcessMemoryInfo` takes a *process* handle, not a window handle. After you find the window, you can call [`GetWindowThreadProcesId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the process ID, then [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the process. Then you can finally call `GetProcessMemoryInfo` for that handle.

When you do call it, you don't need the `BOOL WINAPI` at the beginning. You normally want to assign the return value so you can check whether it succeeded, something like:

```
bool succeded = GetProcessMemoryInfo(process, /* ... */);
```

Edit: here's a really simplistic demo:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    HWND window = FindWindow(NULL, argv[1]);
    DWORD id;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &id);

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, id);

    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info = {0};
    info.cb = sizeof(info);
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(process, &info, sizeof(info));

    std::cout << info.WorkingSetSize;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another issue to be aware of - don't declare an object of type `PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`.  Instead, create an object of type `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`, then pass a pointer to it into `GetProcessMemoryInfo` after filling out the appropriate fields.  Otherwise the function won't give you back any meaningful information about the process.

Comment: I tryed GetWindowThreadProcesId and error:a value of type "HANDLE" cannot be used to initialize an entity type "DWORD". Would you mind showing me what you mean that is a little confusing.

Comment: Tyvm for the code but i get a link error :main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetProcessMemoryInfo@12 referenced in function _main, Also i know this might sound dum but where do i put the window name?

Comment: You have to link against psapi.lib. You pass the window name on the command line when you run it (e.g., `get_mem_info calc.exe`).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Ty i fixed the link error but i am still a noob at programming how do i pass the window name?

Comment: @bob: from the command line, just type in "calc.exe" on the command line after the name you've give the executable. If you're running it from within Visual Studio, you can set the command line arguments in the project settings under "debug". If you prefer, you can just hard code "calc.exe" in like you had it previously.

Comment: Hmm i think this might be working, i got "335650816" from the program and i had it look at a program which is 308,904k so says Task manager. Is this right and what is it giving me (byte?)

Comment: @bob: right now it's printing the working set size -- I didn't try to make it particularly useful, just printed out a more or less randomly chosen member of the structure.